# Ping requests to ambiguous hostnames reply with DNS server IP address

Tags: windows-server-2016

I am running Windows DNS 2016 environment. When I ping any host that does not exist anywhere, I get a reply with my DNS server IP Address.

E.g. my DNS server IP address is 192.168.1.5/24 
When I run `ping wretew` (some unknown host), it replies with

```
reply from 192.168.1.5: bytes=32 time=1ms ttl=128
```

Same response is displayed when I `ping wxxxd` or anything else that is not existing anywhere.

However when I ping the right host-name, I get the expected responses.

Comment: You have setup a wildcard host name for your local DNS domain. If you don't need it, remove it.

Comment: Typically a search domain such as `example.com` is configured in your DNS settings that will get appended to unknown host names like `wretew` to generate a fully qualified domain name `wretew.example.com` - When then there is wildcard DNS record `*.example.com`  `wretew` will resolve even though it does not really exist.

Comment: removing the wildcard hostname resolved the issue; thx alot

Comment: @HBruijn you should write that up as an answer, so others with the same issue have it easier to find this question, after Kenneth marks it.